# button in markdown using enduro.js

Tags: javascript, markdown, enduro.js

I followed this guide on how to enable markdown in enduro.js: http://www.endurojs.com/docs/using-markdown

This works ok, but I would like to have button instead of normal anchor link. My markdown looks like this:

```
## Title
Paragraph text

[read more](/linktofullarticle)
```

I would like the readmore link to be a `<button>` instead of `<a>`

the abstractor looks like this:

```
// placeholder abstractor
var abstractor = function () {}

// vendor dependencies
var marked = require('marked')
marked.setOptions({
    renderer: new marked.Renderer(),
    gfm: true,
    tables: true,
    breaks: false,
    pedantic: true,
    sanitize: true,
    smartLists: true,
    smartypants: false
})

abstractor.prototype.init = function(context) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        // initialize abstractor
        resolve()
    })
}

abstractor.prototype.abstract = function(context) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        context['$markdowned_text_hidden'] = true

        // creates the markdowned context
        context.markdowned_text = marked(context.text)

        // abstract directive
        return resolve()

    })
}

module.exports = new abstractor()
```

Note: I also want to keep the standard link as sometimes the link should be a button and other times a link.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add your custom markdown rule on top of the standard markdown.

For example, the markdown to get a button could look like this

```
## Title
Paragraph text

..[read more](/linktofullarticle)
```

Then just catch it and replace by regex in your abstractor code:

```
context.markdowned_text = marked(context.text)
context.markdowned_text = context.markdowned_text
    .replace(/\.\.\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/g, '<a class="btn" href="$2">$1</a>')
```

note: using `<button>` might not work in this case since you want the user to redirect after clicking the button. Just use `<a>` with `class="btn"` and style it like a button.